# installation fail when installing the android plugin for eclipse..

Tags: java, android, android-ndk

```
 Cannot complete the install because of a conflicting dependency.
  Software being installed: Android Traceview 16.0.1.v201112150204-238534 (com.android.ide.eclipse.traceview.feature.group 16.0.1.v201112150204-238534)
  Software currently installed: Eclipse IDE for Java Developers 1.3.1.20100916-1202 (epp.package.java 1.3.1.20100916-1202)
  Only one of the following can be installed at once: 
    Eclipse UI 3.6.1.M20100826-1330 (org.eclipse.ui 3.6.1.M20100826-1330)
    Eclipse UI 3.6.2.M20110203-1100 (org.eclipse.ui 3.6.2.M20110203-1100)
    Eclipse UI 3.6.0.I20100603-1100 (org.eclipse.ui 3.6.0.I20100603-1100)
  Cannot satisfy dependency:
    From: Android Traceview 16.0.1.v201112150204-238534 (com.android.ide.eclipse.traceview.feature.group 16.0.1.v201112150204-238534)
    To: org.eclipse.ui 3.6.2
  Cannot satisfy dependency:
    From: Eclipse IDE for Java Developers 1.3.1.20100916-1202 (epp.package.java 1.3.1.20100916-1202)
    To: org.eclipse.epp.package.java.feature.feature.group [1.3.1.20100916-1202]
  Cannot satisfy dependency:
    From: EPP Java Package 1.3.1.20100916-1202 (org.eclipse.epp.package.java.feature.feature.group 1.3.1.20100916-1202)
    To: org.eclipse.platform.feature.group [3.6.1.r361_v20100909-9gF78GrkFqw7GrsZnvz0JWNTeb6fue6896L]
  Cannot satisfy dependency:
    From: Eclipse Platform 3.6.1.r361_v20100909-9gF78GrkFqw7GrsZnvz0JWNTeb6fue6896L (org.eclipse.platform.feature.group 3.6.1.r361_v20100909-9gF78GrkFqw7GrsZnvz0JWNTeb6fue6896L)
    To: org.eclipse.rcp.feature.group [3.6.1.r361_v20100827-9OArFLdFjY-ThSQXmKvKz0_T]
  Cannot satisfy dependency:
    From: Eclipse RCP 3.6.1.r361_v20100827-9OArFLdFjY-ThSQXmKvKz0_T (org.eclipse.rcp.feature.group 3.6.1.r361_v20100827-9OArFLdFjY-ThSQXmKvKz0_T)
    To: org.eclipse.ui [3.6.1.M20100826-1330]
```

Answer (score 0):

May be you are doing something wrong. below are the basic steps.

Start Eclipse, then select Help > Install New Software....

Click Add, in the top-right corner.

In the Add Repository dialog that appears, enter "ADT Plugin" for the Name and the following URL for the Location:

https://dl-ssl.google.com/android/eclipse/

Click OK

Note: If you have trouble acquiring the plugin, try using "http" in the Location URL, instead of "https" (https is preferred for security reasons).

In the Available Software dialog, select the checkbox next to Developer Tools and click Next.

In the next window, you'll see a list of the tools to be downloaded. Click Next.
Read and accept the license agreements, then click Finish.
Note: If you get a security warning saying that the authenticity or validity of the software can't be established, click OK.

When the installation completes, restart Eclipse.

You can also read more here http://developer.android.com/sdk/eclipse-adt.html

Answer (score 0):

It looks to me like you are trying to install the plugin on a base Eclipse system that is too old to support it.  Check the prerequisites / dependencies listed in the documentation for the specific version of the plugin that you are trying to install.

It is also possible that there is a dependency conflict with another plugin that you've installed previously.

---

The simple solution is to start with a clean, up-to-date Eclipse base install (with no 3rd party plugins), and add the Android plugin to that.  Then add the other plugins, if you want to take the risk.

In my experience, it is a good idea to create a backup copy of your Eclipse installation before you start adding plugins ... just in case something goes wrong.  And take notes of what plugins / versions you are install from where, in case you need to repeat the process in the future.

Comment: youre right guys.. the version of eclipse is old.. i downloaded a new version its eclipse 3.7 indigo.. it works.. ahahaha.. tnx guys!..