# Numerous error messages when attempting to install ADT in Eclipse

Tags: java, android, eclipse, adt

I am attempting, rather unsuccessfully to setup an Android development environment using Eclipse on a 64 bit Mac running Mac OS X Lion.

I have downloaded the latest version of Eclipse from http://www.eclipse.org/downloads/packages/eclipse-ide-java-ee-developers/heliossr1

When I go to Help >> Install New Software I get the option to add the http://dl-ssl.google.com/android/eclipse repository that brings up the available ADT downloads. However, when attempting to install I am greeted with these error messages which mean nothing to me.

```
    Your original request has been modified.
    "Android Development Tools" will be ignored because it is already installed.
    Cannot complete the install because of a conflicting dependency.
    Software being installed: Android Traceview 18.0.0.v201203301601-306762(com.android.ide.eclipse.traceview.feature.group 18.0.0.v201203301601-306762)
    Software currently installed: Eclipse IDE for Java EE Developers 1.3.1.20100916-1202 (epp.package.jee 1.3.1.20100916-1202)
  Only one of the following can be installed at once: 
    Eclipse UI 3.6.1.M20100826-1330 (org.eclipse.ui 3.6.1.M20100826-1330)
    Eclipse UI 3.6.2.M20110203-1100 (org.eclipse.ui 3.6.2.M20110203-1100)
    Eclipse UI 3.6.0.I20100603-1100 (org.eclipse.ui 3.6.0.I20100603-1100)
  Cannot satisfy dependency:
    From: Android Traceview 18.0.0.v201203301601-306762 (com.android.ide.eclipse.traceview.feature.group 18.0.0.v201203301601-306762)
    To: org.eclipse.ui 3.6.2
  Cannot satisfy dependency:
    From: Eclipse IDE for Java EE Developers 1.3.1.20100916-1202 (epp.package.jee 1.3.1.20100916-1202)
    To: org.eclipse.epp.package.jee.feature.feature.group [1.3.1.20100916-1202]
  Cannot satisfy dependency:
    From: Java EE IDE Feature 1.3.1.20100916-1202 (org.eclipse.epp.package.jee.feature.feature.group 1.3.1.20100916-1202)
    To: org.eclipse.platform.feature.group [3.6.1.r361_v20100909-9gF78GrkFqw7GrsZnvz0JWNTeb6fue6896L]
  Cannot satisfy dependency:
    From: Eclipse Platform 3.6.1.r361_v20100909-9gF78GrkFqw7GrsZnvz0JWNTeb6fue6896L (org.eclipse.platform.feature.group 3.6.1.r361_v20100909-9gF78GrkFqw7GrsZnvz0JWNTeb6fue6896L)
    To: org.eclipse.rcp.feature.group [3.6.1.r361_v20100827-9OArFLdFjY-ThSQXmKvKz0_T]
  Cannot satisfy dependency:
    From: Eclipse RCP 3.6.1.r361_v20100827-9OArFLdFjY-ThSQXmKvKz0_T (org.eclipse.rcp.feature.group 3.6.1.r361_v20100827-9OArFLdFjY-ThSQXmKvKz0_T)
    To: org.eclipse.ui [3.6.1.M20100826-1330]
```

I have also tried downloading the ADT-18.0.0.zip file and adding it as an archive, which produces the same results.

Anyone shed any light on this?

Comment: You should completely remove all android installations from eclipse   (which means you have to find some folders. In linux they're in ".eclipse" in your home dir) and try again. You can also try adding/enabling eclipses own repositories for updates and addons and so on. That fixed some dependency issues for me.

Comment: I am trying that now. Don't think it will work however.

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/q/9049595/741249?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have the same problem. I have the latest Eclipse but get the same error when I try to update the ADT. I have a work around however. I resolved the issue by updating everything except the TraceView. To do this, I clicked on Eclipse/About Eclipse and clicked on the button "Installation Details" at the bottom. Then I selected Android components one by one and clicked on Update. Except for TraceView, everything else updated fine.

BTW, if you are trying to install ADT first time, see if you can disable TraceView and continue.

Good Luck